# How to access the ip address of a client in java

Tags: spring-boot, networking, server, ip, devops

In my code in want to print the ip address of the client system.My front end and back end codes are in same server.My client systems ip is 192.168.2.3(not actual) and server up is 192.168.38.1(not actual).When i run the services its getting that local host address only (ie localhost).

request.getRemoteAddr();

I am using this code to get the ip.

Why its happening and how can I resolve that?

Comment: How are you accessing the server from client ? If you access it through localhost, you'll get localhost IP on server.

Comment: @Vasan if it is via localhost what should I do?

Comment: If client uses localhost to access server, request.getRemoteAddr will return localhost only. That cannot be changed. But if you want the 192.* client IP, try accessing the server using _its_ 192.* IP. This makes the request go through the network adapter (wifi/lan) interface rather than localhost interface